# k8s prometheus: which metric in prometheus tells namespace's cpu and memory limit

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

We use `prometheus(v: 1.7.0)` as monitor for a `k8s(v: 1.10.11)` cluster. In k8s, we have multiple `namespaces`. Are there in `prometheus metric` to tell the `CPU` and `memory limit` in each `namespace`?

Or in the other words, how to find metrics in prometheus to read resourcequota's limits.cpu and limits.memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built-in CPU and memory limits in namespaces, but you can define them with [resource quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/).

So, you don't need Prometheus to get this information, but you can just query the ResourceQuota objects through the API server.

If you need this information in Promtheus, you can use the [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) Prometheus exporter, which exposes [metrics about ResourceQuota objects](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/resourcequota-metrics.md).

Comment: If namespace has been already created, could we apply quota later on? In development environment, we already create different namespaces, but we did not assign resourcequota, could we later assign cpu and memory limit to each namespace?

Comment: Yes you can, but the quotas will most probably not be enforced on the existing resources. That is, if the actually used resources already exceed the quota that you're applying, the workloads are not affected. You can restart all the pods after applying the quota so that the quota is enforced.

Comment: Great news. But how to set resources limit to created ns. Are there some command example?

Comment: Create a ResourceQuota object as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/).